# Joining multiple numpy tensors

Tags: numpy, tensor

I have three numpy tensors `a1 = (20,256,256,3)` , `a2 = (30,256,256,3)` , `a3 = (40,256,256,3)`

I want to join them so that I get another vector `a4 = (90,256,256,3)`

```
90 = {20 + 30 + 40}
```

I tried `np.concatenate`, `np.vstack`. Didn't work

Comment: How did you try `np.concatenate`?

Comment: a4 = np.concatenate((a1,a2,a3),axis = 0)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to sum over the unique column values of your stacked array. This solution works, but it relies on a for loop:

```
import numpy as np

# your input arrays
a1 = np.array([20, 256, 256, 3])
a2 = np.array([30, 256, 256, 3])
a3 = np.array([40, 256, 256, 3])

# your expected output
a4 = np.array([90, 256, 256, 3])
a4_test = np.zeros_like(a4)

a = np.vstack([a1,a2,a3])

for j in list(range(a.shape[1])):
    a4_test[j] = np.sum(np.unique(a[:,j]))

# yields [ True  True  True  True]
print(np.equal(a4, a4_test))
```